# Рисуем шрифт размером N pt

Tags: php

Использую imagick. В общем, вопрос в заголовке - как?)

П.С. Возьмем, к примеру, `300 dpi`.

Comment: вопрос решен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать опцию -pointsize

```
convert -pointsize 24 ...
```

Пример: [Simple Text Label](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#label)